# One or many elements in xsd schema

Tags: xml, xsd

How can you define an xsd to either have a single element, or a group of different elements.

```
<xs:complexType name="oneOrMany">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="one" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="two" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="three" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="four" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Consider the snippet above. I either want a new element (call it five), or ALL of elements one, two, three and four present. No other combination should be valid. It also needs to be backwards compatible with the existing structure.

Do I need to group 1 2 3 and 4? Or create a new complex object from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little modification of your complexType should do it:

```
<xs:complexType name="oneOrMany">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="one" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="two" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="three" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="four" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="five" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```